# Modify Dalvik Virtual machine in Android for getting method and Class name for Fine Grained Access Control

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik

For implementation a Fine Grained Access control on Android, I need to have class and method names in Run time.

for getting class names,I  should modify Android Dalvik virtual machine.
I have some questions about modifying the Dalvik VM.

1. How can I modify the dalvik VM so that I can make decision dynamically? This should not be done with a external program.
2. I know I must done hooking in some method of Dalvik Vm, but I don't know which method Should be hooking and what?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm curious why you need fine grained access controls? The dalvik/art runtime is not a security barrier, and any controls you implement there can be worked around by a determined (or possibly not so determined) adversary.

Comment: @JesusFreke I don't wanna implement controls in DVM, I only need when each methods of one class of any application enter to DVM, DVM write the class or methods names in a txt file, I have defined my class permissions in Manifest (I have modified AOSP)and now I need class name for applying my fine grained accesss control on class level.

Comment: Still, @JesusFreke has a point that in order to provide reliable access control, you need a strong security boundary to protect your logic from tampering. Placing any substantial part in the DVM is therefore an invitation for an adversary to manipulate your system. Remember that the app has full access to its own process space. Also, as a further note, keep in mind that Dalvik was superseded by ART in Android 5, so your solution's applicability would be restricted to versions prior to Lollipop.